# Correctly over-loading a stringbuf to replace cout in a MATLAB mex file

Tags: c++, matlab, cout, mex, stringbuffer

MathWorks currently doesn't allow you to use `cout` from a mex file when the MATLAB desktop is open because they have redirected stdout.  Their current workaround is providing a function, [mexPrintf, that they request you use instead](http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1600/1605.html).  After googling around a bit, I think that it's possible to extend the `std::stringbuf` class to do what I need.  Here's what I have so far.  Is this robust enough, or are there other methods I need to overload or a better way to do this?  (Looking for portability in a general UNIX environment and the ability to use `std::cout` as normal if this code is not linked against a mex executable)

```
class mstream : public stringbuf {
public:
  virtual streamsize xsputn(const char *s, std::streamsize n) 
  {
mexPrintf("*s",s,n);
return basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char>>::xsputn(s,n);
  }
}; 

mstream mout;
outbuf = cout.rdbuf(mout.rdbuf());
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't really want to overload `std::stringbuf`, you want to overload `std::streambuf` or `std::basic_streambuf` (if you want to support multiple character types), also you need to override the overflow method as well.

But I also think you need to rethink your solution to your problem.

`cout` is just an `ostream`, so if all classes / functions takes an `ostream` then you can pass in anything you like. e.g. `cout`, `ofstream`, etc

If that's too hard then I would create my own version of `cout`, maybe called `mycout` that can be defined at either compiler time or runtime time (depending on what you want to do).

A simple solution may be:

```
#include <streambuf>
#include <ostream>

class mystream : public std::streambuf
{
public:
    mystream() {}

protected:
    virtual int_type overflow(int_type c)
    {
        if(c != EOF)
        {
            char z = c;
            mexPrintf("%c",c);
            return EOF;
        }
        return c;
    }

    virtual std::streamsize xsputn(const char* s, std::streamsize num)
    {
        mexPrintf("*s",s,n);
        return num;
    }
};

class myostream : public std::ostream
{
protected:
    mystream buf;

public:
    myostream() : std::ostream(&buf) {}
};

myostream mycout;
```

And the cout version could just be:

```
typedef std::cout mycout;
```

A runtime version is a bit more work but easily doable.

Answer (score 9):

Shane, thanks very much for your help.  Here's my final working implementation.

```
class mstream : public std::streambuf {
public:
protected:
  virtual std::streamsize xsputn(const char *s, std::streamsize n); 
  virtual int overflow(int c = EOF);
};
```

...

```
std::streamsize 
mstream::xsputn(const char *s, std::streamsize n) 
{
  mexPrintf("%.*s",n,s);
  return n;
}

int 
mstream::overflow(int c) 
{
    if (c != EOF) {
      mexPrintf("%.1s",&c);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

...

```
// Replace the std stream with the 'matlab' stream
// Put this in the beginning of the mex function
mstream mout;
std::streambuf *outbuf = std::cout.rdbuf(&mout);
```

...

```
// Restore the std stream buffer 
std::cout.rdbuf(outbuf);
```

Comment: Restoring the std stream buffer proved to be very important. Without doing so my mex function seemed to get some sort of memory problem and crashed matlab upon re*compiling*.

Answer (score 2):

I have changed the OP's final implementation a little bit, adding a constructor and destructor. Creating an object of this class automatically replaces the stream buffer in `std::cout`, and when the object goes out of scope, the original stream buffer is restored. RAII!

```
class mxstreambuf : public std::streambuf {
   public:
      mxstreambuf() {
         stdoutbuf = std::cout.rdbuf( this );
      }
      ~mxstreambuf() {
         std::cout.rdbuf( stdoutbuf );
      }
   protected:
      virtual std::streamsize xsputn( const char* s, std::streamsize n ) override {
         mexPrintf( "%.*s", n, s );
         return n;
      }
      virtual int overflow( int c = EOF ) override {
         if( c != EOF ) {
            mexPrintf( "%.1s", & c );
         }
         return 1;
      }
   private:
      std::streambuf *stdoutbuf;
};
```

To use the stream buffer in a MEX-file, simply:

```
mxstreambuf mout;
std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
```

... and don't worry about forgetting anything.

Answer (score 0):

`cout` is a particular character output stream.  If you want a `cout` that writes to a file, use an [`fstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/fstream/), particularly an [`ofstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ofstream/).  They have the same interface that `cout` provides.  Additionally, if you want to grab their buffer (with `rdbuf`) you can.