# How to judge a value type (int or double) in c++ vector?

Tags: c++, matlab, templates, stdvector, mex

I am using a template in C++ to display the vector content in Matlab with `mexPrintf`. Similar to `printf`, `mexPrintf` need an input of the type (%d or %g). As a prior, I know the type of the vector. Do I have a method to judge the type in the template? I want to `mexPrintf("  %d", V[i])` for `vector<int>`, and `mexPrintf("  %g", V[i])` for `vector<double>`.Is it possible? My example code is below.

```
template<typename  T> void display(T& V)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < V.size(); j++)
    {
        //if
        mexPrintf("\n data is %d\n", V[j]);//int
        //else
        mexPrintf("\n data is %g\n", V[j]);//double
    }
}
```

I may need the judgement for my `if` & `else`. Or any suggestion to another solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the value to a string using [`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string):

```cpp
template<typename  T> void display(T& V)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < V.size(); j++)
    {
        mexPrintf("\n data is %s\n", std::to_string(V[j]));
    }
}
```

But you can also just use the standard way of outputting text in C++:

```cpp
template<typename  T> void display(T& V)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < V.size(); j++)
    {
        std::cout << "\n data is " << V[j] << '\n';
    }
}
```

In the latest versions of MATLAB `std::cout` in MEX-files is automatically redirected to the MATLAB console. For older versions of MATLAB you can do this using the trick in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41276477/7328782).

Comment: I prefer the standard way of C++ very much. Thank you for relating this point in Matlab.

Answer (score 4):

Since C++17 you can use [Constexpr If](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If):

```
template<typename T> void display(T& V)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < V.size(); j++)
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<typename T::value_type, int>)
            mexPrintf("\n data is %d\n", V[j]);//int
        else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<typename T::value_type, double>)
            mexPrintf("\n data is %g\n", V[j]);//double
        else
            ...
    }
}
```

Before C++17 you can provide helper overloads.

```
void mexPrintfHelper(int v) {
    mexPrintf("\n data is %d\n", v);//int
}
void mexPrintfHelper(double v) {
    mexPrintf("\n data is %g\n", v);//double
}
```

then

```
template<typename T> void display(T& V)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < V.size(); j++)
    {
        mexPrintfHelper(V[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Very useful answer for overloads. Thank you.